# Dynamically generating div's on the basis of partial view being rendered by foreach loop

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I am trying to dynamically generate div's on the basis of the partial view rendered by the foreach statement. I am successful in generating the dynamic divs on the basis of an array values. However, when the partial view is rendered the second time or the third time, the divs are not generated separately  , but get added to the previous div length. Here is more description to the issue that I am facing.

**View**

```
<div class="section-wrap break" id="ServicePlan_PrioritySectionNew" data-bind="foreach:application.viewModel.SupportedPriorities">
            @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Home/ServicePlan/_Priority1.cshtml");}
        </div>
```

**Partial View**

```
<div class="priority-timeline">
<div class="timeline-list">
    <div class="timeline-list-items" style="margin-left: 75px">
        <h6 data-bind="text:hasValue(Title())?Title():'&nbsp;'"></h6>
        <div class="timeline-bar" id="resizable">                
            <div class="bar-steps">                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$.each(applicationview.viewModel.SupportedPriorities(), function (i, v) {
    ActivityMonthData(i, v);
});
}

function ActivityMonthData($this, priorityObj) {
var priorityMonth = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
var timeFrame = priorityObj.TimeFrames();

if (timeFrame.trim().length > 0 && timeFrame.trim() != "On-going") {
    var startMonth = jQuery.inArray(timeFrame.split('-')[0].trim(), priorityMonth);
    var endMonth = (timeFrame.split('-').length > 1) ? jQuery.inArray(timeFrame.split('-')[1].trim(), priorityMonth) : startMonth;
} else {
    var startMonth = 0;
    var endMonth = 11;
}

var temp1 = priorityMonth.slice(startMonth, priorityMonth.length);
var temp2 = priorityMonth.slice(endMonth, priorityMonth.length);
priorityMonth = $.merge(temp1, temp2);

var activityMonth = startMonth;
var activityTotalMonth = [];
for (var i = startMonth; i <= startMonth + 2; i++) {
    activityMonth = activityMonth + 1;
}
for (var j = 0; j <= activityMonth; j++)
    activityTotalMonth.push(j);

$.each(activityTotalMonth, function (i, v) {
    var div = $('<div>').addClass('counts')
    $('.bar-steps').append(div);
});
```

}

In the .js file at the end, I am generating the div dynamically based on the values of the **activityTotalMonth** for the class **.bar-steps** the code works fine as well. However, at the run time the UI shows the combination of the all the looping values that are iterated by the $.each statement and display the same amount of divs on every partial view rendered.

How can i rendered divs on the basis of the value from **activityTotalMonth** of different partial view rendered

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$('<div/>').appendClass..` Also.. Try to empty `$('.bar-steps')` before starting new `append`

Comment: .appendClass is not available for jquery

Comment: Sorry.. Correction.. It should have been `addClass`.

Comment: When I try to empty the $('.bar-steps') it removes everything. I am using the .empty function of jquery. as $(.bar-steps').empty() under the document.ready()

Comment: Seems like you should be able to do this with another `foreach` Knockout binding.

Answer (score 1):

$('.bar-steps') is applied on all the divs with that class name on the entire page ... that is why you are getting similar output. And since you are already using Knockout there is no need for you to do the DOM manipulation using jquery (the way you are doing it with the for $.each to create divs). So a good solution for you should be to use Knockout "foreach" binding on the activityMonth

```
//replace 
//var activityTotalMonth = [];
$this.activityTotalMonth = ko.observableArray();

//modify your HTML with this 
<div class="bar-steps" data-bind="foreach:activityTotalMonth">                    
 <div class="counts">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but the foreach binding also does not work :(

Comment: Have you removed the scripts that generate the div elements? if you have done that ... are you getting any javascript error?